# Linker optimizing out shared library

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

Using CMake and gcc/clang compilers I want to create a shared library out of this file (`Registrator.cpp`):

```
#include ...

namespace
{

struct Registrator
{
    Registrator()
    {
        ...
    }
    ~Registrator()
    {
        ...
    }
} g_registrator [[gnu::used, gnu::visibility("default")]];

} // namespace
```

This object is not used anywhere else. Its responsibility is solely to do some things during its (de)construction.

When defining it as:

```
add_library(${libname} OBJECT Registrator.cpp)
```

It is a way to prevent the linker from optimizing out this TU as in `OBJECT` case all sources get into final executable.

However I want to be able to use this as a `SHARED` library as well. And in case of:

```
add_library(${libname} SHARED Registrator.cpp)
```

the library is not linked at all, and `gnu::visibility("default")` unfortunately doesn't quite cut it.

Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks for help in advance.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming use of g++, you can disable the [`--as-needed`](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2010-November/031991.html) link behavior. This is enabled by default, which can lead to the issue you are seeing. Try passing the link flag to disable it using CMake's [`target_link_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html#command:target_link_options) command:

```
add_library(${libname} SHARED Registrator.cpp)
target_link_options(${libname} PUBLIC "-Wl,--no-as-needed")
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply. Using target_link_options() command works, however it applies this flag to every other library I link with eg. gcc -Wl,--no-as-needed ${libname} MyOtherLib will also apply linker option to MyOtherLib. I would like to avoid this behavior. Is there any way to apply this flag on library level?

Comment: You can try using the `PRIVATE` keyword, instead of `PUBLIC`.